# OpenCV input from open windows

Tags: python, image, opencv, user-interface

I have created a program with OpenCV that takes x amount of image files from a folder and then displays all of them scaled down to the same size, such that they don't overlap and I can view them all. I would like to be able to give the program some input on which
images to "keep". The easy way is to give some text input with the index of the file being shown to select. But I would like to be able to do it directly from the GUI. Can anyone suggest how I could (with a bunch of open windows) click on one of the images to close it, while at the same time storing it's index/position. And then, when I'm done 'clicking' to save, I would use `cv.waitKey(0)` to shut down the rest of the windows.

Here's my code. Take note that all of this is wrapped in a for loop, which is looping over each image file, with a counter variable 'I' being incremented.

```
       img = cv.imread(file,cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

       height = img.shape[0]
       original_length = img.shape[1]

       new_height = 250
       if original_length > 400:
           original_length = 400
       size = (original_length, new_height)
   

       img = cv.resize(img, size, interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)

       cv.namedWindow(f'image: {i}', cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
       cv.imshow(f'image: {i}', img)

       if x > 1200:
           x = 0 
           y  = y+ 260
       cv.moveWindow(f'image: {i}', x, y)     
       x = x + original_length

       if wait_to_display:
           cv.waitKey(0)

cv.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Can't you use setMouseCallback?

Comment: yeah, setmousecallback, click pictures to toggle their selection. -- `waitKey` does _not_ "shut down" anything. `waitKey` causes GUI to work. if you don't call it, your OS will kill your program for being unresponsive.